# How can I convert a String to a DOMSource in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I need some help. In my `String` filedata variable I stored an XMLdocument. Now I want to convert this variable to a `DOMSource` type and use this code:

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( filedata ) ) ); 
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
```

and transform by javax.xml.transform.Transformer :

```
 Transformer transformer = XMLTransformerFactory.getTransformer(messageType);
 StreamResult res = new StreamResult(flatXML);
 transformer.transform(source, res);
```

But my flatXML is empty after transformation. I checked my doc variable, and it contains my XML document and parsed everything right. If I change my source to the real path everything is ok and works fine :

```
 Source source = new StreamSource("c:\\temp\\log\\SMKFFcompleteProductionPlan.xml");
```

I think my problem situated in this line of code :

```
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
```

but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why are you trying to construct a DOMSource? If all you want is a source to supply as input to a transformation, it is much more efficient to supply a StreamSource, which you can do as

```
new StreamSource(new StringReader(fileData))
```

preferably supplying a systemId as well. Constructing the DOM is a waste of time.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot) now it's work)) but please, can you explain, why it doesn't work with DOMSource?)

Comment: No, sorry, I can't immediately see what's wrong. But then, you don't say what DOM and XSLT implementations you are using; it could be something implementation-specific.

Answer (score 2):

**FYI:** There are no constructor of Class DOMSource having argument only String like DOMSource(String).
The constructors are as follows:
i)`DOMSource()` 
ii)`DOMSource(Node n)` 
iii)`DOMSource(Node node, String systemID)` 
Please see : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMSource.html

Comment: Sorry, but I passed Document type variable to DOMSource: `DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);` not just a String

Comment: I must convert my Document variable to Node type?

Comment: can you help me, how can I convert my Document to Node?

Comment: As per my knowledge:

NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("description");
After that if you iterate, you will get the node, for e.g. first node like: Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(0); But not sure this will going to help you. :(

Comment: What about this decision:  `Node document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(filedata.getBytes()));` ? But the result is the same(

Comment: But it doesn't solve my problem. My flatXML variable still empty because my source variable empty